# Riak in a Spring application

Tags: java, spring, spring-data, riak

After July 6th 2011 I cannot find any newer versions of spring-data-riak than 1.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT. Has the project been abandoned? If using Riak in a Spring project, should I be using Basho's java-client library instead? Or is there a replacement to spring-data-riak I should check out?

Cheers

Nik

Comment: I found the project on GitHub. It's still got some activity on it. https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-keyvalue